# How to let the django pass an instance of HttpRequest to views using POST method

Tags: django, django-views, response

Hi could you help me solve the following problem. In the Django tutorial it says

### When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that contains metadata about the request. Then Django loads the appropriate view, passing the HttpRequest as the first argument to the view function. Each view is responsible for returning an HttpResponse object.

Now I have written a view as follows and it renders the first form in my application. It looks like it has been passed with GET instead of POST as I get that "Method is not post" in the application. Can I change this? Since this is the first view loaded, so the response is not returned by another view. I am not sure where to change it.

```
def intro(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    return HttpResponse("Method is not post")
    ....
```

Comment: You want to change the response that the `GET` request sends ?

Comment: hi I meant the HttpRequest object passed to intro view.

Comment: This question is very unclear. You make the request a post by, well, sending a POST request.

Comment: Hi I can not send a POST request to it. In the urls.py file I path('', views.welc, name='welc'),

Comment: So Django (whatever this means) will load intro view by passing the HttpRequest . This request is not sent by another view (where I can specify that it need to return a POST request), instead it is sent by Django(again, whatever this means) as it is the first form created.